# chntpw is unable to read my windows drive

Tags: linux, ssd, bluetooth, windows-11, kde

Similar problems have been posted before but the solutions there are too old/didn't work for me. So I am making a new post. I am trying to follow the guide [here](https://github.com/spxak1/weywot/blob/main/guides/bt_dualboot.md) to allow myself to use the same bluetooth device for two different OSes on the same machine (i.e., pairing the device to both Windows and Linux and being able to connect from both devices without errors). The steps include cd'ing `/mnt/win/Windows/System32/config` and then running `$ chntpw -e SYSTEM`. However, I get the error below:

```
$ chntpw -e SYSTEM
chntpw version 1.00 140201, (c) Petter N Hagen
openHive(SYSTEM) failed: No such file or directory, trying read-only
openHive(SYSTEM) in fallback RO-mode failed: No such file or directory
chntpw: Unable to open/read a hive, exiting..
```

I have made sure to turn off hibernation in windows using powershell and then running `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` but that still didn't fix it. I had other issues with Windows (for example the search crashing) so I ran `sfc /scannow` and the DISM `restore-health` command to fix it, it still didn't work. However, other issues that I was facing with Windows were fixed.

System Info:

```
Operating System: KDE neon 5.25 / Windows 11
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.2
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.95.0
Qt Version: 5.15.5
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-52-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: 82FG
System Version: IdeaPad 5 15ITL05 Ua
```

lsblk output:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 226.4G  0 part /mnt/win
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0    50G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   200G  0 part /home
```

Comment: You should disable Windows' Fast Startup and shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that my laptop, unlike my desktop, has a directory named `system` instead of `SYSTEM` inside of `C:\Windows\System32\config`. So the command I had to run was `chntpw -e system` and not `chntpw -e SYSTEM`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for saving time.